# Slider Control Update Label Based on Value Error on Slider_ValueChanged

Tags: wpf, vb.net, slider, wpf-controls

Trying to do something super simple and I am not getting it.  New to this programming stuff a bit.  I have a slider control.  I have two labels.  One I have bound to the value of the slider to show the chosen value.  I have another label that I have verbiage in.  If the slider value is 1 I want it to say 'Player'.  If it's greater than 1 I want it to say 'Players'

```
  <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
  <Slider x:Name="sliderhunter" Minimum  = "1" Maximum = "8" Width="200" TickFrequency = "1" Value="2" 
   TickPlacement = "BottomRight" ValueChanged = "sliderhunter_ValueChanged" Margin = "10" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>


  </Viewbox>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderhunter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Left" Height="68" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="50" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="43,34,469,0" />
  <Label Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:FieldModifier="Public"   Content="Hunters" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="50" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="95,34,343,0" x:Name="txtHunter" />
```

And my simple code behind.

```
  Private Sub sliderhunter_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double)) Handles sliderhunter.ValueChanged
        If e.NewValue > 1 Then

            txtHunter.Content = "Players"
        Else
            txtHunter.Content = "Player"
        End If

    End Sub
```

It gets hung up on the else with the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  I don't get that, either. I have the value set to 2 so the else shouldn't even come into it, yet. I have spent the last two hours on this.  If you can help, please use crayons in your explanation.  Like I said, still trying to learn all this stuff.

@emoacht

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=GameProject
  StackTrace:
   at GameProject.winSetGameSettings.sliderhunter_ValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 e) in C:\Users\mgobl\source\repos\GameScoreBoard\GameScoreboard\winSetGameSettings.xaml.vb:line 2571
```

Here is the error screen:
[image: Error Details]

Comment: Could you post the whole exception message?

Comment: @emoacht - I edited my question with the pics and the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question why there's `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception, it's simply because XAML language is also order sensitive language.

What means if You'd put `sliderhunter` slider after `txtHunter` lable there won't be any exception, beacaue when `ValueChanged` on slider is called `txtHunter` is already initialized.

But in general if You want to make this app 'the right way', I'd suggest dig in MVVM pattern and move the logic from code behind to the ViewModel.

There's a ton of examples and tutorials about MVVM, here's first link that pops up under MVVM and WPF search:
https://intellitect.com/blog/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/

Comment: well, now I feel even more dummer.  That was it.  Moved the TextBox above the slider and bingo!  I will look into the MVVM stuff, as well.  Feel like I should learn it.  I have just been a bit intimidated by it.  I dabbled in some MVC stuff and I just couldn't grasp it so I feel MVVM is going to be the same challenge.  Thanks for your help on this.  emoacht thank you,  too.